# Why is this error so unclear?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code:

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "bar.h"

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar bar);
};
#endif //FOO_H
```

bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include "foo.h"

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Foo foo);
};
#endif //BAR_H
```

If I compile that, I get the following error message:

```
expected ')' before 'foo'        bar.h      line 9
```

After looking on this website, I fixed it by using a forward declaration of `Foo` in `bar.h`, and `Bar` in `foo.h`.

My question is, why does the compiler make this error sound like a syntax error, whilst it's actually not ? I would think that catching such an error and return a proper error message would be quite simple.

Comment: `#include bar.h` and `#include foo.h` are incorrect. Those file names should be quoted.

Comment: When encountering an error like this, a compiler has to take an educated guess at what the programmer intended. It doesn't always choose wisely.

Comment: This *is* a syntax error. Depending which of the two headers you include first, there is no type `Foo` or type `Boo` when you first use it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: @cHao sorry, not the same computer, I fixed it (they are quoted in my files)

Comment: Try several compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) & [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)...)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I thought there would be some kind of specialized error, like `Unknown type error` or something

Comment: @Insomgla that's a possible error, but in cases like this, from a language syntax perspective, there are other possible options. So the compiler picks one it thinks is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is very hard to parse. When compiler does not know that `Foo` is name of some type then it expects that we try to declare members with that name in `Bar`. Code does not parse as any of valid variants of member declarations.

Old compilers just diagnosed such cases as "syntax error". Modern compilers try to be friendlier. The diagnostic likely tries to help us to correct the code towards one of such (or some other similar) valid member declaration.

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar (Foo());
    Bar (*Moo);
    Bar Roo();    
};
```

Unfortunately it guessed totally wrongly since `Foo` was not meant as member name but as a type of parameter of constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You have headers with unresolved circular dependency. That is when your code somewhere includes "foo.h" first then after preprocessing it will become

```
class Bar // expanded from #include "bar.h"
{
public:
    Bar(Foo foo); // Foo is not declared at this point
};

class Foo // rest of foo.h content
{
public:
    Foo(Bar bar);
};
```

if your code includes "bar.h" first then after preprocessing it will become

```
class Foo // expanded from #include "foo.h"
{
public:
    Foo(Bar bar); // Bar is not declared at this point
};

class Bar // rest of bar.h content
{
public:
    Bar(Foo foo);
};
```

So there is an error in both cases.

To get around this issue you need to utilize proper forward declarations:

```
// foo.fwd.h
#ifndef FOO_FWD_H
#define FOO_FWD_H

class Foo;

#endif // FOO_FWD_H

// bar.fwd.h
#ifndef BAR_FWD_H
#define BAR_FWD_H

class Bar;

#endif // BAR_FWD_H
```

and include them into headers instead of header with complete class declaration:

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "bar.fwd.h"

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(Bar bar);
};
#endif //FOO_H

// bar.h
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include "foo.fwd.h"

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar(Foo foo);
};
#endif //BAR_H
```

and then include headers with class definition only into .cpp or implementation file.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, my question was more about why does C++ does have such an unclear error message ? Why not a simple message stating that type of the object is not known ?

Comment: @Insomgla C++ suffers from inconsistent syntax with high complexity that been clogging for ~30 years. And it's getting worse with every new standard. For example there are like 7 different ways to initialize a variable, yet standard committee adds 8th one instead of deprecating / removing at least 4 of redundant existing ones. It is a miracle that compilers still somehow manage to at least show potential erroneous spot.

Comment: @Insomgla - C++ itself doesn't define any error messages. The error text is up to the compiler vendor. Different compilers give messages with varying degrees of quality. The error text is not something C++ itself is defined to have.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yep sorry, I typed too fast. As stated in my question, I meant the compiler. I'll try different compilers to see if I get something a bit clearer.

Comment: @Insomgla you may find that using multiple compilers is very helpful beyond readable error messages. A logic error that does not show up (usually because the undefined behaviour invoked by the code is implemented by the compiler in a manner similar to what you expected) in compiler A is revealed by the different decisions made by compiler B.